# Should I choose Dependency Injection or Factory Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection

I am investigating about Dependency Injection. And I found that: most of the examples quoted for usage of Dependency Injection, we can solve using the factory pattern as well.

Could you please help me compare strong/weak point between DI and Factory pattern? Should I always choose Dependency Injection instead of factory pattern? Or it is depend on specified project?

How can I know what is the best solution? What is best practice for that?

Comment: Can you please show an example of both patterns. That would help understand how you intend on using them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets look at the difference between them.

With DI, objects are created externally and "injected" for use by the client object.
Injection is commonly done via constructor.

However, in complex situations, its common to inject a DI container to create the dependency objects, including all sub-dependencies. So it then looks like Abstract Factory!

With Abstract Factory, an instance of a concrete Factory class is injected and the dependency objects are instantiated by the client object.

So DI and Abstract Factory are pretty much the same, when you consider that in both cases, factory objects are passed to the client to enable it to create its dependencies.

In simple cases only, the dependent objects are created externally and passed to the client object. This is how Strategy Pattern works.

Since DI containers are so prevalent now, and used so extensively in frameworks, they have effectively replaced Abstract Factory, at least as a pattern that is frequently spoken about. DI containers are vastly more complex entities than were ever envisaged for Abstract Factories (I believe).

So there is no best practice!

Answer (score 4):

You should use both.

Factory is about finding the right implementation of an interface based on the given parameters and returning an instance of it. It is one way to solve the problem that a class cannot be responsible for both instantiating itself and doing something else, because it violates SRP.

DI is about injecting the dependencies usually by passing parameters to the constructor of the actual class. It is needed because high level code should not know about which implementation of the low level code it uses, just that this implementation cooresponds with a certain interface. Otherwise we would violate DIP.

So the factory is very much compatible with the DI. Actually the DI container is just an automated factory, which pulls in information from annotations, config files, etc. to be able to make an Applcation instance and inject its dependencies. Of course its dependencies have dependencies too and so on, so it would be a long code if you would write it manually, so there is a good chance it would be a god object. You can fix that by defining factories, which would make it a lot shorter, but somehow people like automation better.

Comment: what does "dependency" mean in this context?

Comment: @snr Well dependency is a broad concept. Normally it just means that a part of code depends on another part of code. In some languages you can pass the dependency to the dependent code as a parameter e.g. with a function name, lambda function, object, etc. We do this when we have many alternative implementations with a common interface e.g. common parameter list by functions or common interface by objects and we want to choose between them. Dependency injection is when we pass it as a constructor or setter parameter. In the case of DI container we choose dependency based on the configuration.

Answer (score 2):

@pcperth: From Xamarin University, they mentioned that both have pros & cons point:

[image]

[image]

In addition, I think with DI, classes are created 1st and our program keep it during running time then it can waste memory (in case we need to optimize memory).

That 's my opinion, but actually I don't know what is better or should we use in specified case. Then I need some discussion there.

Cheer!

Answer (score 1):

I like to use a simple dependency injection over an interface.
Just pass an object which implements the interface to the constructor.

This has the additional advantage that you can easily mock the interface and run test on your build server / computer. As the deployment takes really long with Xamarin, try to do as much as possible with unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

This is the rule of thumb I follow: If the instantiation requires parameters that are available only on runtime (e.g. a user input) then use Factory pattern. Otherwise, use DI. Note that the factory itself should be accessed through DI.

For example, the user is given a choice between generating a Pie Chart or a Bar Chart. However, both use some kind of Data access service - say `DataAccessContext`. The ChartFactory will look like this

```
DataAccessContext context {get; set;}
public ChartFactory(DataAccessContext context) //Comes from DI
{
   this.Context = context;
}

public Chart GetInstance(string type) // Factory instance
{
  if(type == "Pie")
    return new PieChart(context);
  if(type == "Bar")
    return new BarChart(context);
  throw new ArgumentException("Invalid choice");
}
```